# How to align two in-line elements within a block

Tags: html, css, xml, pdf, xsl-fo

I am using xsl-fo to render a PDF. I need to create a table header for my TOC that has one element("Chapter Contents") on the left and the other element("Page") on the right, and the two elements appear on the same line.

Currently, I create two fo:inline elements to wrap the text, which are then be wrapper under a fo:block element. I have my xslfo code looks like:

```
 <fo:block text-align="left">
        <fo:inline color="#0082C8"   font-size="8pt" font-family="serif" font-weight="normal" >Chapter Contents:  </fo:inline> 
        <fo:inline  font-size="8pt" font-family="serif" font-weight="normal" alignment-adjust="alphabetic" >Page    </fo:inline>   
 </fo:block>
```

This code will simply put both two elements on the left-hand side. If I did make two in-line elements into two separate blocks, they will be on different lines! Also, adding in text-align="right" into the second  will have no effect.

Could experts offer some help? I want both elements appear on the same line and one on the very right while other on the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about xsl-fo, but in "normal" html/css you would give a float:left to the first element and a float:right to the second.

Comment: I did try put in float:left and float:right, but it seems does nothing :(

Comment: It seems that you need a special block -> <fo:float float="right">  See the second example: http://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo-en/xsl-fo/xsl-fo-introduction/the-float-concept

Comment: That page is a 404 now, so it would have been great if you had answered the question rather than just linking.

Answer (score 0):

With

**<fo:leader/>**

you can output text on left, middle and right side; and also define 'spacer' (like dots etc.). Although it's not very intuitive, it works very well.